# spark streaming can not do the toDF function

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am trying to make a spark Streaming application that connects to Flume.

I managed to save the data when it is an RDD, but if I try to convert it to a DataFrame using the toDF function it makes an error. I am working with the shell so I can't see what the error is.

this is the code I am doing:

```
//importing relevant libraries
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.streaming._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.flume._
import org.apache.spark.util.IntParam
import org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel

//creating the spark streaming configuration
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(5))
val stream = FlumeUtils.createStream(ssc, "0.0.0.0", 44444, StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY_SER_2)

//starting the streaming job
val textStream = stream.map(e => new String(e.event.getBody.array) )
val numlines = textStream.count()
numlines.print()
textStream.foreachRDD { rdd =>
  //some stuff that needs to be created
  import java.util.Date
  val d = new Date
  //delimeter of '&'
  val rdd_s = rdd.map(line => line.split("&"))
  val rdd_split = rdd_s.map(line => (d.getTime.toString, line(2), line(3).toInt))
  //only saves the data if the toDF is comented out.
  rdd_split.saveAsTextFile("/flume/text/final/")

  //creating the data-frame - if commented out, the data will be saved to file
  val sqlContext = SQLContext.getOrCreate(rdd.sparkContext)
  import sqlContext.implicits._  
  val df = rdd_split.toDF("moment", "ID","amount")
  df.saveAsTextFile("/idan/streaming/flume/text/final/withtime")
}

ssc.start()
```

**found the answer to this**
what i needed to do is create a lazy singleton of the sqlContext to create the DataFrame.
here is the final of the singleton code:

```
//creating the case class for the DataFrame
case class Record(moment:String, name:String, id:String, amount:Int)
/** Lazily instantiated singleton instance of SQLContext */
object SQLContextSingleton {
  @transient private var instance: SQLContext = null
  // Instantiate SQLContext on demand
  def getInstance(sc: SparkContext): SQLContext = synchronized {
    if (instance == null) {
      instance = new SQLContext(sc)
    }
    instance
  }
}
```

and to create the DataFrame i needed to create the singleton for it:

```
val sqlContext = SQLContextSingleton.getInstance(rdd_s.sparkContext)
import sqlContext.implicits._
val df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd_s.map(line => (d.getTime, line(0), line(1), line(2), line(3))))
```

**edit:**
it gives me this error:

```
16/08/09 13:16:05 ERROR scheduler.JobScheduler: Error running job streaming job 1470748565000 ms.1
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper.conf(ClientWrapper.scala:205)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.hiveconf$lzycompute(HiveContext.scala:554)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.hiveconf(HiveContext.scala:553)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext$$anonfun$configure$1.apply(HiveContext.scala:540)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext$$anonfun$configure$1.apply(HiveContext.scala:539)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.configure(HiveContext.scala:539)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.metadataHive$lzycompute(HiveContext.scala:252)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.metadataHive(HiveContext.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext$$anon$2.<init>(HiveContext.scala:459)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.catalog$lzycompute(HiveContext.scala:459)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.catalog(HiveContext.scala:458)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext$$anon$3.<init>(HiveContext.scala:475)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.analyzer$lzycompute(HiveContext.scala:475)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.analyzer(HiveContext.scala:474)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertAnalyzed(QueryExecution.scala:34)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.<init>(DataFrame.scala:133)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$.apply(DataFrame.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.createDataFrame(SQLContext.scala:417)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLImplicits.rddToDataFrameHolder(SQLImplicits.scala:155)
    at $line46.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:58)
    at $line46.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:48)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(DStream.scala:661)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(DStream.scala:661)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:426)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:49)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.Job.run(Job.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(JobScheduler.scala:224)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:224)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:224)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler.run(JobScheduler.scala:223)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
16/08/09 13:16:08 ERROR scheduler.ReceiverTracker: Deregistered receiver for stream 0: Stopped by driver
```

did anyone happend to have this kind of problem and know how to help?
Thanks :)

Comment: pls see [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Help others reproduce the problem

Comment: Are you not able to see the error in spark ui logs ?

Comment: it was very long so i edited the question.

Comment: which line is the ClientWrapper.scala:205?